# What different video split ffmpeg VS opencv?

Tags: python, image, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I used opencv and ffmpeg to do the work of framing the video.

opencv

```
import cv2

# 영상의 의미지를 연속적으로 캡쳐할 수 있게 하는 class
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture("D:/godzillakingofmonster/GodzillaKingOfMonsters_clip.mkv")

count = 0

while(vidcap.isOpened()):
    # read()는 grab()와 retrieve() 두 함수를 한 함수로 불러옴
    # 두 함수를 동시에 불러오는 이유는 프레임이 존재하지 않을 때
    # grab() 함수를 이용하여 return false 혹은 NULL 값을 넘겨 주기 때문
    ret, image = vidcap.read()

    # 캡쳐된 이미지를 저장하는 함수 
    print("D:/godzillakingofmonster/frame/frame%d.jpg" % count)
    cv2.imwrite("D:/godzillakingofmonster/frame/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)

    print('Saved frame%d.jpg' % count)
    count += 1

vidcap.release()
```

ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i \"{target_video}\" \"{save_folder_path}/{media_name}_%08d.{exp}\"
```

I am wondering which of the two methods will give you more accurate results.

When a frame is divided, another frame is saved. Why are there different results?

Which method, ffmpeg or opencv, is more accurate and prints the results closer to the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming ffmpeg is also storing jpg files. In both methods you don't specify the amount of jpg compression so you're running with default values and they are likely different.

Output to an uncompressed format such as `.png` to get 100% accurate images in both ffmpeg and opencv.